# Typewriter.typeString (Add a string that doesn't delete?)

Tags: javascript

My JS Typewriter Code is Below:

Question #1:  How can I add a String that does not delete?  I'd like to have a set of words "We are' as the start of the sentence that does not delete.  The .typeStrings would type out next to 'We are' as normal:  Example www.cantercompanies.com

Question #2:  How can I change the font color between the fixed 'We are' and the .typeStrings text color?

```js
 <script>
 var app = document.getElementById('typewriter');
 
 var typewriter = new Typewriter(app, {
     loop: true,
     delay: 40,
 });
 typewriter.typeString('transportation')
    .pauseFor(550)
      .deleteAll(1)
    .pauseFor(900)
     .typeString('auto dealers')
     .pauseFor(550)
      .deleteAll(1)
    .pauseFor(900)
     .typeString('realtors')
     .pauseFor(550)
     .deleteAll(1)
      .pauseFor(900)
      .start(0)
   <script>
```

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://safi.me.uk/typewriterjs/) there is no option to have a string prefix that is not deleted. What you can try is to re-initialise the typewriter with the intiial string every time you delete something. Also try wrapper classes for styling the initial text differently. Or even you can try deleteing only chars that are AFTER the initial string that you want

Comment: Alternatively you can open an issue on github repository of typewriter to have this new feature

Comment: Question for you:  www.cantercompanies.com ... what are your thoughts on their typewriter effect?  What are they doing for the “we are”?  Thank you for your reply, Nikos.

Comment: My impression is that they use 2 typewriter instances one instance types 'we are' and the other types the rest. I did not find the relevant code but this is an option you can try

Answer (score 3):

You can add HTML elements directly into `typeString()`. This means you can wrap all the text with spans and add a class name or throw the styles directly inside the `<span/>`.

```js
var app = document.getElementById('app');

var typewriter = new Typewriter(app, {
  wrapperClassName: 'test',
  delay: 50,
  loop: true,
});

typewriter
  .typeString('<strong>We are: </strong>')
  .pauseFor(550)
  .typeString('<span style="color:green;">transportation</span>')
  .pauseFor(550)
  .deleteChars(14)
  .pauseFor(900)
  .typeString('<span style="color:blue;">auto dealers</span>')
  .pauseFor(550)
  .deleteChars(12)
  .pauseFor(900)
  .typeString('<span style="color:purple;">realtors</span>')
  .pauseFor(550)
  .deleteChars(8)
  .pauseFor(900)
  .start();
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/typewriter-effect/dist/core.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Hope this helps,